# find all points in a circle

Tags: opencv, drawing, geometry, points

I draw a circle with a fixed input Point. Now I really want to get a vector of all the Points in that circle includes filled area inside. I tried the code below but it only get the border. I can not use Contours function because I have used it many times so it would be very complicated. Please give me advice thank you so much

```
 vector<Point> allpoints;
 Point center = Point(370, 200);

void getPoints()
{
   Size axes(20, 20);
   ellipse2Poly(center, axes, 0, 0, 360, 1, allpoints);
}

void draw(Mat &BGR_frame)
{
    circle(BGR_frame, center, 20, Scalar(0, 255, 0),CV_FILLED ,2);
    getPoints();
}
```

Comment: some images and a better explanation/problem definition would help. Problem is unclear.

Comment: have you considered calculating the euclidean distance from the center you've selected ? If it is less than the radius (20), you can push_back() the point in your vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to draw the circle on a black initialized mask, and retrieve the non-black points from there:

```
void draw(Mat &BGR_frame)
{
    circle(BGR_frame, center, 20, Scalar(0, 255, 0),CV_FILLED ,2);

    // Black initialized mask, same size as 'frame'
    Mat1b mask(frame.rows, frame.cols, uchar(0));

    // Draw white circle on mask
    circle(mask, center, 20, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 2);

    // Find non zero points on mask, and put them in 'allpoints'
    findNonZero(mask, allpoints);
}
```

Alternatively, you can scan all pixels of the matrix, and keep points that satisfy the equation of being internal points of the circle:

```
Point c(370, 200);
int r = 20;

void draw(Mat &BGR_frame)
{        
    circle(BGR_frame, c, r, Scalar(0, 255, 0),CV_FILLED ,2);

    for (int y = 0; y < mask.rows; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < mask.cols; ++x) {

            // Check if this is an internal point
            if ((x - c.x)*(x - c.x) + (y - c.y)*(y - c.y) <= (r*r)) {
                allpoints.push_back(Point(x,y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```